# JQuery - How to add a class to every last list item?

Tags: jquery, css, class, each

Got some code here that isn't working:

```
$("#sidebar ul li:last").each(function(){
      $(this).addClass("last");
});
```

Basically I have 3 lists and want to add a class (last) to each item appearing last in each unordered list.

```
<ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li class="last">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Hope that makes sense,
Cheers!

Comment: Is this added class used to add a margin at the bottom of the list? If so, you could just use the ul's margin-bottom property instead. If not, carry on. =P

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `.each` in this case, you can just do `.addClass` directly.  jQuery will apply all commands to the entire set of matched elements.

Comment: Also, a good site to test out different selectors and see how they work can be found here: http://www.woods.iki.fi/interactive-jquery-tester.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Easy mistake to make.  Try this:

```
$("#sidebar ul li:last-child").addClass("last");
```

Basically :last doesn't quite do what you think it does.  It only matches the very last in the document, not the last in each list. That's what :last-child is for.

Comment: Perfect! - Thanks for taking the time to help me out mate, appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

with jquery add this

```
$("ul li").last().addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that won't work is due to the fact that `:last` only matches one element.  From the jQuery documentation:

> Matches the last selected element.

So what your code is doing is getting a set of all the `<li>` elements in a `<ul>` and then from that set taking the last value.  Example:

```
 <ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
 </ul>
```

Your code would return the element `<li>6</li>`.  (Internally, it'd collect `<li>1</li>` to `<li>6</li>` and then lop off the last one and return it).

What you're looking for is what the other answers here have said: `:last-child`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could give your list an id and use that as an context to jquery-call.

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul id="anotherList">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

And then you can do:

```
jQuery("li:last", "ul#myList").addClass("lastItem");
```

Now the last li in the first list would have class "lastItem".

Edit: Sorry, misread the question. Ignore this please.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add class to 3 separate lists you can assign a class for them and use 'each':

```
$('#sidebar ul.class li:last-child').each(function(e){
    $(this).addClass("last");
});
```

This should work exactly as you expected.

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
$('#sidebar ul li:last').addClass('last');
```